# Flex can't handle EOF in Action, or how to?

Tags: c, flex-lexer

### env

- OS: MacOS Monterey 12.6 with apple M1 Pro
- version: flex 2.6.4 Apple(flex-34)

### Problem

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
int yywrap(void) {
    return 1;
}
%}

ID  [a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*
DIGIT [0-9]

%%

{DIGIT}+    {printf("num");}

{ID}    printf("id: %s\n", yytext);

"/*"    {
    int c;

    for ( ; ; ) {
        while ( (c = input()) != '*' && c != EOF )
            printf("%x\n", c);

        if ( c == '*' ) {
            while ( (c = input()) == '*' )
                printf("%x\n", c);
            if ( c == '/' )
                break;    /* found the end */
            }

        if ( c == EOF ) {
            printf( "EOF in comment" );
            break;
        }
    }
}
%%

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ++argv, --argc;
    if (argc > 0) {
        yyin = fopen(argv[0], "r");
    } else {
        yyin = stdin;
    }
    yylex();
    return 0;
}
```

I try this code, hope to handle `EOF` in `Action` by myself. But it fail to handle this file, like:

```
/* **jfiowejfiowe
 *
 *
```

Yes, I just want to test `unclosed comment` in the end of file.

```
lex test.lex
gcc lex.yy.c -o lextest
./lextest comment.c
```

and it output

```
20
2a
66
69
6f
77
65
6a
66
69
6f
77
65
a
20
20
0
0
0
...
```

with endless `0`.

I also try to rewrite `yywrap()`

```
int yywrap() {
    return 0;
}
```

But it output like

```
20
2a
66
69
6f
77
65
6a
66
69
6f
77
65
a
20
20
[1]    57558 segmentation fault  ./lextest comment.c
```

has a `segmentation fault` error.

Also I try `yyterminate` like

```
#define yyterminate() return YY_NULL

int yywrap(void) {
    yyterminate();
}
```

still has a `segmentation fault` error.

Comment: Why don't you just use a flex pattern to match the rest of the comment? It's by far the easiest (and the most efficient).

Comment: Note that `ID  [a-z][z-z0-9]*` is probably a typo at z-z.  But this isn't the problem. Is  there a newline at the end of the input?  If not, it's theoretically invalid. Posix requires the last line to be newline terminated. Lex should not respond as it does (this is an example in the manual!), but it's not unusual for programs to malfunction when the newline is missing. You could always run the flex generated code in a debugger to see what's going wrong.

Comment: I know use `start condition` can solve this. But sometimes when you want to handle `string` with complicate `escape rule`, use `start condition` will have too many `condition` and `rule`, so I want to handle it just in `Action`.  @rici

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Up to version 2.6.0, the `input()` function returned `EOF` on end of input. For reasons which are not at all clear to me, this was changed for version 2.6.1 (released in March, 2016); since then, `input()` returns 0 on end of input, making it pretty well impossible to distinguish between end of input and a `NUL` character. The Flex documentation has not been updated to reflect this change.

A very clumsy workaround is available. In `yywrap`, you could set a global flag (or put a flag in the `yyextra` data, for a reentrant scanner), and then you could check the flag after `input()` returns 0. This is not a fully general solution, but it should work in your case.

Alternatively, you could install an older Flex release (2.5.39 and 2.6.0 are both available at the [Github release page](https://github.com/westes/flex/releases). Or you could download the source for version 2.6.4 and patch the file `flex.skl` at line 1859, changing it from `return 0` to `return EOF`.

Whatever the reason for the change, it's certainly a bug, either in the behaviour or in the documentation, and it has been reported several times: most recently, apparently, by you, and previously as [issue 212](https://github.com/westes/flex/issues/212) in 2017 and [issues 444](https://github.com/westes/flex/issues/444) and [448](https://github.com/westes/flex/issues/448) in 2020. That last one contains references to bug reports in other places (debian, for example).

On the whole, I feel that the use of `input()` should be avoided if at all possible. It has its uses, but in most cases, you'll find it faster and more convenient to use start conditions. In the particular case of multiline comments, even that's unnecessary; they can be recognised with a pair of patterns. (One for correct comments, and another one to flag an error for unterminated comments.)

As a final note about your attempt to terminate the lexical scan from `yywrap`:

The only thing you can do in `yywrap` to terminate the scan is return 1. If you return 0, you are promising that you have reset the `yyinput` so as to make more input available. If you don't do that, the result is undefined (which means, bad). The `yyterminate` action is only valid in lexer actions; it cannot be used anywhere else. (Although it looks like a function, it's actually a macro which assumes that it is being expanded in the context of an action, and will have undefined consequences if expanded in a different scope.) So the segfaults you experienced are not surprising.

Comment: Thx, you show me the detail.

Comment: @hstk: I added a paragraph about your use of `yywrap(0)` and `yyterminate()` inside `yywrap`. If you have a specific requirement which seems to require `input()`, I'm happy to look at it. Feel free to ask a new question.