# flex: segfault when reading to EOF with `input()`

Tags: flex-lexer

The program below works as expected when reading from stdin, but segfaults when it is instead lexing a buffer.

The key thing about this example is that one of the rules uses `input()` to gobble from `"!"` to EOF (yes, it looks as if I could use a `"!".*` pattern, but that doesn't produce the intended results in the real case).

```
$ flex -o eof.c eof.lex
$ cc -o eof eof.c
$ echo -n 'one two!three four' | ./eof
word:<one>
-> 1
-> 2
word:<two>
-> 1
buf=<three four>
-> 3
```

That's fine, but when I instead `./eof 'one two !three four'`, which scans the contents of a buffer set up by `yy_scan_string`, I get a segfault inside `yy_get_next_buffer`.

I can't work out which part of the flex manual is telling me I should expect that to happen.  Can anyone point out to me what I'm doing wrong?

What's happening is that the lexer is finding its way to the end of file, as expected (and an `<<EOF>>` action confirms this), but not stopping there, despite the presence of the `noyywrap` option, and collapsing when it can't find a ‘next’ buffer.

Points:

- Option `-d` doesn't illuminate.
- It is, of course, a little hard to follow what the generated code is doing, but looking at the location of the segfault, it is indeed around the place where the code is checking for `yywrap`, so it *should* be getting the message that there is no more input coming.
- The only real illustration of using `input()`, in the flex manual, is in a case where hitting EOF is reported as an error.  Here, I'm doing essentially the same as in that example, but regarding EOF as an acceptable end of the scan.
- The same behaviour appears when using a reentrant scanner.
- It's worth noting that `input()` returns 0, not `EOF`, at EOF, despite what Sect.8 illustrates (cf. [flex repo issue](https://github.com/westes/flex/issues/548), and links there), and despite the rather mysterious note about a ‘“real” end-of-file’ in Sect.20.  I have a suspicion that this remark in Sect.20 is telling me something terribly important, but I can't work out what.
- The `-n` option to `echo` means that it is not supplying a newline, so the sequence of input characters should be identical in the two cases.
- This is with flex 2.6.4, on both macOS and Linux.
- The `flex-help` list, pointed to by the flex repo, seems to be moribund.

Program:

```
ALPHABETIC  [a-zA-Z]
WS      [^a-zA-Z!]

%option noyywrap nounput

%%

{ALPHABETIC}+   {
    printf("word:<%s>\n", yytext);
    return 1;
}
{WS}+   {
    return 2;
}

"!"         {  // gobble to end of input
    char buf[80];
    for (int idx=0; (buf[idx] = input()); idx++) /* empty */ ;
    printf("buf=<%s>\n", buf);
    // YY_FLUSH_BUFFER; /* makes no difference */
    return 3;
}

%%
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    switch (argc) {
      case 1: break;
      case 2:
        yy_scan_string(argv[1]);
        break;
      default:
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [string]\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    int token;
    while ((token = yylex()) != 0) {
        printf("-> %d\n", token);
    }
}
```

Further thoughts (edit):

There's [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73767676/) where the answer discusses flex's behaviour at EOF (thanks to the commenter for the pointer).  But that answer expands on the problem of `input()` returning zero rather than `EOF`, as noted above, and points to a similar set of github issues, without really coming to any very definite conclusions.  What I'm seeing here still looks rather like a bug in buffer/EOF/yywrap handling, without me being able to point to a line in the documentation which makes that definitive.

Further edit: clarify that it's not a newline at the end of the stdin version that makes it work.

On reflection, I think this *is*, after all, a candidate for a bug in flex, and I've reported it as [issue 636](https://github.com/westes/flex/issues/636) there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flex can't handle EOF in Action, or how to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73767676/flex-cant-handle-eof-in-action-or-how-to)

Comment: That might be the same underlying issue (I hadn't found that question before – thanks), but the answer expands on the problem of `input()` returning zero rather than `EOF`, as noted in this question, and points to a similar set of github issues, without really coming to any conclusions. The remarks later in that answer aren't wrong, but don't really address the issues here. What I'm really looking for, I suppose, is some argument why what I'm seeing doesn't count as a bug.

Comment: I keep on running into this sort of problem. Istr ensuring there was a newline terminating the yy_scan_string once sorted one of my problems out, but I might have changed the grammar as well.

Comment: @njamescouk Thanks for the good suggestion.  I've had problems with 'missing' newlines at EOF, but only (if I recall correctly) in cases where the lexer was (implicitly or deliberately) reading entire lines, and thus getting confused when it got EOF first. That is a common glitch when lexing from a string (which will tend not to have newlines) in contrast to a file (which will).  I did actually confirm I got the same behaviour in stdin without newline, but haven't illustrated that above -- I'll edit.

Comment: There are several questions here, but the one relevant to the title is obvious: reading into a fixed-size buffer without checking.